# CORS request issue (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I'm developing a server at Node js and my front-end at Angularjs, but I'm getting an error when I try to make a request from my front-end:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8085/server/authenticate/.
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

My code at my server.js

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Oringin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,accept');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
        res.statusCode = 200;
        return res.end();
    }
    else{
        return next();
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

NOTE: back-end and front-end are not at the same port, I'm trying to make it work as a CROSS-Origin resourse.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-` **`Oringin`** is not a CORS header :) The error message is indeed correct that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not being set on the response.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realized about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express();
 
app.use(cors());
/* Make your app with CORS support: for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors*/
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a little error in your header name `Access-Control-Allow-Oringin`

Try this

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,POST,OPTIONS');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','X-Requested-With,content-type,Authorization,accept');
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS'){
    res.statusCode = 200;
    return res.end();
}
else{
    return next();
}
```

});